# The anchor tag that allows one to jump to a specific section is not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, anchor

I tried to use the anchor link so that I can jump to a specific part of the code and in the webpage when I click on[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oINs7.png) that link it should open up that part on the same page without redirecting to other but it is not working[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKzBd.png)
The webpage should show "lorem ipsum...." only when I click on home or destination but it shows it without clicking

I tried to get this code to work and I hope someone could help me solve the problem

Comment: Please try to provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question by sharing your code, ideally in a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It is working, but your browser has nowhere to scroll to, because everything is visible already.

If you want to visualise the targeted element, you can use [the `:target` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target).

Ideally, you would have a headline that is linked.

For testing, you could also add a `min-height: 100vh` on the text, to make it at least as high as the window, to make scrolling necessary.

```css
:root {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

h2:target {
  outline: .1rem solid orange;
}

p {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h2>On this page</h2>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#s1">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#s2">Section 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<h2 id="s1">Section 1</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum</p>

<h2 id="s2">Section 2</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```